# Powershell DSC - MSFT_RoleResource

Tags: powershell, dsc

I have a problem related to MSFT_RoleResource, I have recovered a DSC script that you can find below:

[image]

The compilation in .mof works as shown below:

[image]

Once the compilation is finished I want to make an Azure policy, the compilation works as shown below ( it's very strange because when i compile the script i have error who say replace the PSDesiredStateConfiguration By PSDresource):

[image]

I want to test it afterwards but it sends me this error:

[image]

Can you help me?

Thank you so much

I tried to redo the manipulation on a blank machine, uninstall Powershell 7 and reinstall .

Comment: What is the target operating system edition and version?

Comment: thank you for you feedback i try compile in Windows 10 21H2 / Windows Server 2016 / 2019 / 2022, in the end I want to be able to create a policy in Azure